# Selenium - Running multiple xml files in TestNG.xml

Tags: selenium

When running below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <suite name="ForEverGreen TestNG Suite" >
  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="./testscript.xml" />
    <suite-file path="./email.xml" />
  </suite-files>
 </suite>
```

Getting the error :

> Error: org.testng.TestNGException: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:341)

Comment: you need to tell us more than this, can not help you with limited information

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `suite-file path` is wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <suite name="ForEverGreen TestNG Suite" >
  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="./testscript.xml" />
    <suite-file path="./email.xml" />
  </suite-files>
 </suite>
```

Can you please try:

1. make sure `testscript.xml` and `email.xml` are spelled correctly?
2. put `testscript.xml` and `email.xml` into the same directory with `ForEverGreen TestNG Suite`
3. remove `./`from `testscript.xml` and `email.xml`